# Sql anywhere engine got crashed when i perform many execute update using jconn4 library from the android application

Tags: android, sqlanywhere, jconnect

am using jconn4 library to connect my android application to the sql anywhere database, everything is good, the engine was launched in 32 bit , so when am trying to perform execute update many times, the engine is crashed i don't know why, i got an advice from an expert, he told me to launch the engine in 64-bit , so i did what he told me, now when i perform the execute update many times, the engine doesn't crash, but the execute update action is dropped and my application is stucked,with no error, just waiting for the statement to be completed, so i can see that my connection is blocked, any idea ?

i tried to launch the enginer in 64 bit, but it doesn't work

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved, i was performing two requests at the same time via different threads, my project is so big, and the database is too, thanks guys